# Could not load .Net assembly that has unmanaged dependencies

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, unmanaged

We have bought a library which does some signal processing.

This library is written in C++ and it provides two .Net wrappers.

If we reference only the .Net wrapper, we are able to build, but when running it, we receive an exception, telling us that it can't find the c++ dlls.

If I copy the Native dlls manually, everything works fine.

What is the **best** way to handle this issue? I mean, to have automatically copied that C++ dll file in the output directory of our project by referencing this .NET wrapper dll only.(This library is being used in several projects, which are used in different windows applications).

We can't add C++ dll as reference, since they are not managed code.

For the example, let's say that my project has the following architecture:

```
/
  Src/
    ApplicationA/
      ProjectAUsingReference/
    ApplicationB/
      ProjectBUsingReference/
  Lib/
    /LibXYZ
      WrapperDll.dll
      UnManagedDllOne.dll
      UnManagedDllTwo.dll
```

All my applications have the same output path, but we can build only the application A, or only the application B. So an additional goal would be to not copy if the file already exists(with the same date/size?)

Comment: Simple idea: use "Post-build event" to add "copy" command that duplicates this DLL. Another idea: add unmanaged DLL to project as "content" and select "Copy to output directory" flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways to solve this issue:

1. Create a Post-build event in each project which references the managed dlls. The Post-build event will have copy command to copy the native dlls from source to destination.
2. Add your unmanaged dlls as link to your projects and mark it to copy to output directory.
   (these two already said in comment by GoodGuyStoft)
3. If your project is inhouse, add the DLL path to PATH variable, it works without much modification. Remember to deploy your native dlls along with your project.

Regards
Kajal

Comment: I like the first proposition, because I don't want to add them as content(and update them) for every project that use it. Is there a way to debug post build event, because I've currently one test with Xcopy, and it seems to work in the commandline when I try to execute it, but it doesn't copy anything when building.

Comment: Tools > options , set the build output verbosity to diagnostics mode